# Bare World Satellite Map Base Layer and Tile Server?

Tags: satellite, tile-server

I'm fairly new to mapping, and am working on a custom data visualization that will be presented on top of a Leaflet map. We'll be placing our own geoJSON polygons on the map (including labels) and would like to have a bare satellite map base layer as the background (i.e. no administrative or other labels).

I've found the following satellite map layers and tile servers:

**Mapbox**: https://www.mapbox.com/maps/satellite#the-data - requires registration, and offers up to 50,000 map / tile server requests per month in their free tier.

**Maptiler**: https://cloud.maptiler.com/maps/hybrid/ - requires registration and I believe offers up to 100,000 tile server requests per month. Fortuantely too they offer the 'bare' tiles here - https://cloud.maptiler.com/tiles/satellite/ - which is exactly what we want (they also offer custom maps  - which ironically, if using the above satellite tiles with all administrative labels removed via their advanced editor, is no longer in their free tier).

**Esri ArcGIS** World Imagery: https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?layers=10df2279f9684e4a9f6a7f08febac2a9 - which I believe is free to use via a developer account (not sure what the monthly restrictions are).

We really like the map and water color of the Maptiler and Mapbox maps.

Since we're looking for a bare base layer map with no administrative or other labels, is there any other option for including a satellite base layer like the ones from Maptiler or Mapbox in our Leaflet map that doesn't require registration with one of the above services?

Comment: can you make two separate questions please.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] the Question to ask only one question.

Comment: Check out Planet imagery: https://www.planet.com/products/basemap/